# Javascript API for query in Elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

If I do below query in Kibana, results : "`tim is a good boy`" and I want to same thing using js library in eclipse.

```
GET nirv/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "tim" }
    }
}
```

I looked everywhere but did not find much of help. So can anyone provide a bit of code for a query to Elasticsearch using JS API in eclipse. What I mean is that I have a function result which provides me what elasticsearch return for particular query.

Comment: Does eclipse have an HTTP client? Maybe you could use that

Comment: Since I'm new to Software development I don't know much about HTTP client. Can you explain it in details? And I want to use JS API for developing search suggester with Elasticsearch. Anything regarding that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [javascript client library](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js) provided by Elasticsearch?

Their [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/quick-start.html) show examples on how to get started and perform a search with the client:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'nirv'
});

client.search({
  user: 'tim'
}).then(function (body) {
  var hits = body.hits.hits; // "tim is a good boy" should be here *somewhere*
}, function (error) {
  console.trace(error.message);
});
```

Comment: This one does not work. I'm want to use this to provide suggestions on my web page. I came across Browser Builds but did not understood much. Is above code supposed to work, when request is from web page?